# Warden or Devise? What's better for Rails authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

What's better to use for Ruby on Rails authentication? Warden or Devise? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Comment: Asking questions that don't have definitive, fact-based answers is going to earn you close votes. SO isn't here to weigh in on whether X or Y is better.

Comment: So I was thinking about this very same question and was glad to find someone on Stack Overflow had a similar question. I was looking forward to read about people's thoughts on the pros and cons of using a simple low-level tool like Warden or a high-level all-in-one package like Devise.  I am disappointed to see the discussion has been shut down because it is "not constructive".

I fear that Stack Overflow is becoming more and more like Wikipedia, where a coterie of overactive users police the system to such an extent that constructive discussion is choked off.

Answer (score 3):

I tried several solutions for authentication for my rails applications starting from building it from scratch and using several gems like sorcy or authlogic ,,devise is the best as it based on warden but with more features ,,you can check railscasts tutorials for integrating devise with your rails applications 
http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=devise

also devise works good with other authentications like openId and facebook and twitter ,,,

Comment: Thanks for the calrification